# All elements are going behind absolute overlay div

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I have an absolute positioned div that is acting as a color overlay on top of a background image.

The problem I am having is that all the content after this absolute positioned div is laying behind it rather than on top of it. I cant quite work out what's going on. I know it has to be something simple.

Here is my current markup

```css
#callout {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/FAHZdf9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 180px 0;
}

#callout h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#callout p {
  padding: 0 50px;
  color: #fff
}

.bg-color {
  background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="callout">
  <div class="bg-color"></div>
  <h2 class="text-center">Test Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: for a quick solution use `#callout h2, #callout p { position: relative; z-index: 1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than messing with z-indexes, why not just put your content inside the overlay:

```css
#callout {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/FAHZdf9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  
  /* set the size you want this to be */
  height: 400px;
}

#callout h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#callout p {
  padding: 0 50px;
  color: #fff
}

.bg-color {
  /* this does not need to be absolutely positioned*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
  
  /* you can vertical align using flex */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="callout">
  <div class="bg-color">
    <h2 class="text-center">Test Heading</h2>
    <p class="text-center">This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this pete, I was under the impression that anything after the absolute positioned div would sit on top of it by default. Thats the main reason i didnt put the content inside the overlay div. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Unfortunately, when you position something absolutely, it takes it out of the flow of the page and will be stacked in order of other positioned elements in the same stacking context (ie any positioned siblings) based on z-indexes.  [This wiki has some good examples of how z-indexes work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control)

Answer (score 0):

put all your text in div and apply that div some `z-index and position: relative`

like below

```
.callout-text{
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```css
#callout {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/FAHZdf9.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 180px 0;
  }
  #callout h2 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #callout p {
    padding: 0 50px;
    color: #fff
  }
  
   .bg-color {
    background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }
  .callout-text{
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
 <div id="callout">
    <div class="bg-color"></div>
    <div class="callout-text">
    <h2 class="text-center">Test Heading</h2>
          <p class="text-center">This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text.</p>  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to apply any extra z-index. Just set position: relative for .text-center.

Stacking order will put positioned elements above non-positioned ones (unless positioned elements have a negative z-index, but that is irrelevant here).

That is the reason why simply setting position relative for .text-center will do the trick for you.

```
.text-center {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `z-index`:

```css
#callout {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/FAHZdf9.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 180px 0;
  z-index: 50; /* added this */
}

#callout h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#callout p {
  padding: 0 50px;
  //color: #fff;
  z-index: 51; /* added this */
  position: relative;
}

.bg-color {
  background-color: rgba(75, 78, 83, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="callout">
  <div class="bg-color"></div>
  <h2 class="text-center">Test Heading</h2>
  <p class="text-center">This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text.</p>
</div>
```

> think of `z-index` as *priority*; higher the `z-index`, the more "**on top**" it is

Comment: Use the magical wand(`position-relative`) otherwise spell(`z-index`) won't work.

Comment: Ah. my bad. Fixed it.